# How to generate PDF via IText Template

Tags: asp.net, itext

we want to realize the following:

1. Generate PDF with Template,which means set value in AcroFields
2. Create a big details table (structure of table is also in template). In this progress, the details will occupy more than one page.
3. If the detail table is on multi pages, the header of the table should be also on top of the new page.

We found some examples on following website:

- http://kuujinbo.info/cs/itext_template1.aspx
- http://kuujinbo.info/cs/itext_template2.aspx

But the details the founction is omitted there.

> Add content; the code for _do_form_fields(), _get_transaction_details(), and _transaction_summary() are omitted, since they only return strings to add to ColumnText. ColumnText is smart; each call to Go() renders as much text that will fit on the current page and returns a status code that tells you: (1) how much text (to write) is remaining, and/or (2) how much space is still available on the page. On each iteration you add text to the current page, call ColumnText.HasMoreText() to inspect the status, and then Document.NewPage() if necessary.

Is there anyone who had same situation before? We are appreciated that you could offer some tips or suggestions.

Thank you.

best regards,

Cheng Gong

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction in your question. You say you want to fill out an AcroForm (static form), but you talk as if you want an XFA form (dynamic form). Please start by reading chapter 6 of my book: http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf More specifically section 6.3.5. Is that what you need? If so, use that code. If not, clarify. Right now your question can't be answered because your requirements aren't clear and your references are confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already making a mistake in the first step of your requirements.

You say "Generate PDF with Template,which means set value in AcroFields."

The first part is OK: you want to generate a PDF with a template. However, this doesn't mean setting values in AcroFields. That's only one option. It's the option you take if you consider PDF being the digital equivalent of paper. The form is static: every coordinate is fixed. You just fill out data at the appropriate places. If the data doesn't fit the designated areas, you're out of luck. I already referred to [chapter 6 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf) in a comment. You can also see how AcroForms work in a longer tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YwDME0Fl1c (This tutorial is almost completely dedicated to creating a report from a data set.)

Another way to create PDF from a template is by using the XML Forms Architecture. In this case (if you have a pure XFA form), your PDF is a container for XML. You can then inject XML data into this form and the form will adapt itself depending on the data. A one-page form can easily grow into a 20-page document when filled out. This is explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0wzj84tnmw (Note that the video dates from 2012. The product I present has been finished and the results are much better now.)

Alternatives to this approach could be to create a template in HTML. I often refer to this solution as a *poor man's XFA solution*. This solution requires XML Worker. You can see an example in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=clWoDrEEl50

This is a general answer. I couldn't be more specific because your question isn't clear. You first need to make your mind up regarding the approach. Right now, you talk about `AcroFields` and at the same time about `ColumnText`. In the long tutorial, this is described as *the hard way*. See also the [corresponding online samples](http://demo.itextsupport.com/itextsamples/). It is very confusing why you're asking a very difficult question before asking the simple questions. Unless of course, you already have the answer to those simple questions. If so, please share these answers.

Comment: Dear Bruno,

Thank you so much for your detailed explaination. Your answer already guid me to the right direction. I will accept this as answer and start study the book first.